# How to add scss file globally which should be applied to all the components in angular2 webpack?

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I can apply scss to components using syntax

```
styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss', '../assets/css/styles.scss']
```

But this style is only visible to particular component.

I want to use '../assets/css/styles.scss' across all the components.

Though using css file globally is easy but scss file is not seem to be working that way.

To configure my webpack for sass, added following line -

```
{
     test: /\.scss$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main app component where all your other modules will appear via router outlet or so, include your global scss there .For eg.
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './app.styles.scss' ]
})

Comment: This way its only visible to that particular component not even its child component added under html.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access the folder location from the webpack like this.

```
{
     test: /\.scss$/,
     loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/css/[name].[ext]'
}
```